# SVG loses Javascript interactivity when embedded in a browser

Tags: javascript, svg, interactive

I have created an SVG file which contains JavaScript.

When I run this SVG file as a stand-alone file in Chrome, it renders okay.

When I embed this SVG in an HTML page, it loses its interactivity.

What I am doing wrong...?

For various reasons, I do not want to use JQuery, D3 or embed the 31 lines of SVG into the HTML page as text.

I want to embed an interactive SVG file in HTML using the  tag as follows:

```
<img src="SVG-STO.svg" style="width:175px  height:258px">
```

Here is a shortened version of the "SVG-STO.svg" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  id="hexMap" viewBox="18 281 175 259"  width="175" height="259" xml:space="preserve"  style = "background-color: #EEEEEE;">

<script type="text/javascript">

<![CDATA[
var objNames =  
{
"AA":{"name":"Hex A","value":"965787"},
"BB":{"name":"Hex B","value":"48986"}
};

function m_over(hover_id) { 
var objName = objNames[hover_id].name;
var objValue = objNames[hover_id].value;
document.getElementById("TEXT_NAME").innerHTML = objName;
document.getElementById("TEXT_VALUE").innerHTML = objValue;
document.getElementById(hover_id).setAttribute("fill-opacity","0.3");}

function m_out(hover_id)   {
document.getElementById(hover_id).setAttribute("fill-opacity", "1.0");
console.log(hover_id);
document.getElementById("TEXT_NAME").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("TEXT_VALUE").innerHTML = "";
}
]]>
</script>
<text id = "TEXT_NAME" x = "28.74" y = "301" font-family = "sans-serif" font-size = "10px" fill = "#FF00FF">Initial</text>

<text id = "TEXT_VALUE" x = "28.74" y = "321" font-family = "sans-serif" font-size = "10px" fill = "#FF00FF">Value</text>             

<path id="AA" style="stroke:#CCCCCC; stroke-width:1px; fill:#00A600;" onmouseover="m_over(this.id);" onmouseout="m_out(this.id);" d="M142.3397,326l-8.66,-15l8.66,-15h17.32l8.66,15l-8.66,15H142.3397z"/>

<path id="BB" style="stroke:#CCCCCC; stroke-width:1px; fill:#19AF00;" onmouseover="m_over(this.id);" onmouseout="m_out(this.id);" d="M142.3397,356l-8.66,-15l8.66,-15h17.32l8.66,15l-8.66,15H142.3397z"/>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG interactivity for `img` tags is disallowed in most browsers for privacy reasons (the browser interprets it as a non-interactive image). To preserve all of the features of interactive SVGs, embed your SVG using the `object` tag instead:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="SVG-STO.svg" style="width:175px; height:258px"></object>
```

For more information on the different ways to embed SVG files, see [this CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/).

Comment: Actually, it's not really "unsupported".  It is deliberately not allowed for privacy reasons.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau That's what I was trying to say - "unsupported" is probably not the word for it though, you're right.